# Solving divergent Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I want to solve this integral.

using Integrate I get it done, but the problem is it results in complex values, which is incorrect for my problem (has no physical meaning).

I'd like to know if there's any other way to solve these kinds of integrals in Mathematica? Is **NIntegrate** acceptable in such cases? since I get real values using NIntegrate, but I'm not sure that would be the correct result.

```
Integrate[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 1)*(1 - y)^3, {y,
   0, 1}]
```

*N.B.  x and a are constant values.

Comment: I get `-((4 (a^2 (a/(-1+x)-3 Log[-1+x]+3 Log[x])+6 a PolyLog[2,1/x]+6 PolyLog[3,1/x]-6 PolyLog[3,E^a/x]))/a^4)`

Comment: yes, thanks. I get the same, so I suppose I should only take the real values, not the imaginary ones? because with my constants for a and x, it results in complex numbers. unless I use NIntegrate.  @asukaminato

Comment: What values are you using for a and x?

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2024 `int(((1 + x*exp(-a*y))^2/(1 - x*exp(-a*y))^2 - 1)*(1 - y)^3, y = 0 .. 1) assuming (a::real, x::real)` correctly calculates the integral under consideration.

Answer (score 3):

This is the condition `cond` under which the integral converges (and is real for real `a` and `x`):

```
cond = a == 0 && x ≠ 1 || a > 0 && (x < 1 || x >= E^a) || 
 a < 0 && (x > 1 || x <= E^a)
```

I found the condition half manually, Mathematica alone was not able to solve it.

For special case of the condition `a == 0 && x ≠ 1` it is:

```
int = (((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 1)*(1 - y)^3 // Factor

Integrate[int /. a -> 0, {y, 0, 1}]
```

---

$$-\frac{4 x (y-1)^3 e^{a y}}{\left(e^{a y}-x\right)^2}$$

$$\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$$

For other cases of the condition `cond` it is

```
Integrate[int, {y, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify
```

---

```
(1/(a^4))4 (-((a^3 x)/(-1 + x)) + 3 a^2 Log[1 - x] + 
   6 a PolyLog[2, x] - 6 PolyLog[3, x] + 6 PolyLog[3, E^-a x])
```

Testing whether integral converges for specific values - `True` means it converges `False` the opposite:

```
cond /. a -> 1 /. x -> 2
cond /. a -> 1 /. x -> 1/10
cond /. a -> 1 /. x -> 10
```

---

```
False

True

True
```

This is the region of convergence for `a` and `x`:

```
RegionPlot[cond, {a, -10, 10}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you consider (0<x<1) and positive a then the result can be put into a form giving real results by using the inversion property of the polylogs as shown in the plot:

0 < x < 1, 0 < a

```
x = 0.999; LogPlot[{NIntegrate[(4*E^(a*y)*
  x*(1 - y)^3)/(E^(a*y) - x)^2, {y, 0, 1}], 
  (4*x)/(a*(1 - x)) + (12*Log[1 - x])/a^2 + (24*PolyLog[2, x])/
a^3 - (24*PolyLog[3, x])/a^4 + 
    (24*PolyLog[3, x/E^a])/a^4}, {a, 0.01, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

for 1 < x and negative a you can use the form given in your post above:

1 < x, a < 0

```
x = 1.01; LogPlot[{NIntegrate[(4*E^(a*y)*
  x*(1 - y)^3)/(E^(a*y) - x)^2, {y, 0, 1}], 
  -(4/(a*(x - 1))) + (12*Log[(x - 1)/x])/
a^2 - (24*PolyLog[2, 1/x])/a^3 - 
    (24*PolyLog[3, 1/x])/a^4 + (24*PolyLog[3, E^a/x])/
a^4}, {a, -4, -0.001}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Comment: `NIntegrate[(4*E^(a*y)*x*(1 - y)^3)/(E^(a*y) - x)^2 /. {x -> 1.01,    a -> 2}, {y, 0, 1}]` results in `538096.` and "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {0.0053386}. NIntegrate obtained 538095.9251324619` and 444170.8516817697` for the integral and error estimates".

Comment: for x>1 you need negative a

Comment: I mean `NIntegrate` hardly handles divergent improper integrals.

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
j = Integrate[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 
1)*(1 - y)^3, {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a, x} \[Element] Reals, 
GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `-(1/(a^4 (-1 + x))) 4 (a^3 + 3 a^2 Log[1 - E^a/x] - 3 a^2 x Log[1 - E^a/x] +  3 a^2 Log[1 - x] - 3 a^2 x Log[1 - x] - 3 a^2 Log[E^a - x] +  3 a^2 x Log[E^a - x] + 6 a (-1 + x) PolyLog[2, 1/x] +  6 (-1 + x) PolyLog[3, 1/x] + 6 PolyLog[3, E^a/x] -  6 x PolyLog[3, E^a/x])`

Second,

```
FunctionDomain[j, x]//FullSimplify
```

> `x < 0 && x < E^a`

Third, its partial verification

```
j /. {a -> 0.25, x -> -10}e
```

> `-0.0861123`

```
NIntegrate[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 
 1)*(1 - y)^3 /. {a -> 0.25, x -> -10}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

> `-0.0861123`

Addition. In 14.0 on Windows 10

```
Integrate[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 1)*
(1 - y)^3, {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a, x} \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]//FullSimplify
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ 1/a^4 4 (a^2 (-(a/(-1 + x)) + 3 Log[-1 + x] - 3 Log[x]) -  6 a PolyLog[2, 1/x] - 6 PolyLog[3, 1/x] + 6 PolyLog[3, E^a/x]),  E^a x < x^2 &&  x < 0 && (Re[Log[x]/a] > 1 || Re[Log[x]/a] < 0 ||  Log[x]/a \[NotElement] Reals)]`

The result is false as

```
RegionPlot[ E^a  x < x^2 &&  x < 0 && (Re[Log[x]/a] > 1 || Re[Log[x]/a] < 0 || 
Log[x]/a \[NotElement] Reals), {a, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

shows.

Addition 2. For the user's convenience,  I'd like to complete the answer by @azerbajdzan. The singularity of the integrand is found by

```
Reduce[1 - x*Exp[-a*y] == 0, y, Reals]
```

> `(a == 0 && x == 1) || (a != 0 && x > 0 && y == Log[x]/a`

The singularity at `y == Log[x]/a` is not integrable, as the result of

```
Series[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 1)*(1 - y)^3,
 {y,Log[x]/a, 1}] // Normal
```

> $\frac{4 (a-\log (x))^3}{a^5 \left(y-\frac{\log (x)}{a}\right)^2}-\frac{12 (a-\log (x))^2}{a^4 \left(y-\frac{\log (x)}{a}\right)}+\left(\left(1-\frac{\log (x)}{a}\right)^2-\frac{4}{a^2}\right) \left(y-\frac{\log (x)}{a}\right)-\frac{\left(a^2-2 a \log (x)+\log ^2(x)-36\right) (a-\log (x))}{3 a^3}$

shows.

Therefore, `Log[x]/a` has not to belong to $[0,1]$ or to have the non-zero imaginary part. This leads to the equation

```
Reduce[Log[x]/a < 0 || Log[x]/a > 1 || 
ComplexExpand[Im[Log[x]/a]] != 0, {x, a}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

> `(x < 0 &&  a != 0) || (0 < x < 1 && (Log[x] < a < 0 || a > 0)) || (x >  1 && (a < 0 || 0 < a < Log[x]))`

Let us show it by

```
RegionPlot[(x < 0 && 
a != 0) || (0 < x < 1 && (Log[x] < a < 0 || a > 0)) || (x > 
 1 && (a < 0 || 0 < a < Log[x])), {a, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Now we turn to the integral

```
Integrate[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 1)*
(1 - y)^3, {y,  0, 1}, Assumptions -> (x < 0 && 
 a != 0) || (0 < x < 1 && (Log[x] < a < 0 || a > 0)) || 
(x >  1 && (a < 0 || 0 < a < Log[x])), GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `-(1/(a^4 (-1 + x))) 4 (a^3 + 3 a^2 Log[1 - E^a/x] - 3 a^2 x Log[1 - E^a/x] +  3 a^2 Log[1 - x] - 3 a^2 x Log[1 - x] - 3 a^2 Log[E^a - x] +  3 a^2 x Log[E^a - x] + 6 a (-1 + x) PolyLog[2, 1/x] +  6 (-1 + x) PolyLog[3, 1/x] + 6 PolyLog[3, E^a/x] -  6 x PolyLog[3, E^a/x])`

Finally, it remains to consider

```
Integrate[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 1)*
(1 - y)^3, {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> a == 0 && x != 1]
```

> `x/(-1 + x)^2`

Comment: Function domain of the output of the integral does not have to coincide with domain where the integral is convergent in case we have some parameters that the integral is dependent on. Integral converges not only for `x<0` as is indicated by output of `FunctionDomain`.

Comment: @three777:Yes, I am aware of it, but the answer is  produced programmatically, not by hand.

Comment: [CASE:5122702] about the wrong result of `Integrate[(((1 + x*Exp[-a*y])/(1 - x*Exp[-a*y]))^2 - 1)* (1 - y)^3, {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a, x} \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]//FullSimplify` has been submitted by me.